# Cross-language (python to scala) sparse data ser/deser?

Tags: json, scala, serialization, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on an application where I would need to represent/construct sparse data on the python side, output the data to storage and then load into an spark/scala application.

Any suggestions as to what formats/libs I should be using for serialization/deserialization?

Comment: Is there a standard way of saving sparse vectors in json with supporting libs (besides rolling out my own)? Currently I'm thinking of using the spark mllib sparse vectors but need to verify the serialization format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `mllib.Vectors` already provides a meaningful string representation and `fromString` method:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, SparseVector

v = SparseVector(5, [0, 3], [1.0, -1.0])
str(v)

## '(5,[0,3],[1.0,-1.0])'

assert Vectors.parse(str(v)) == v
```

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors, Vector}

Vectors.parse("(5,[0,3],[1.0,-1.0])")
// org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = (5,[0,3],[1.0,-1.0])
```

If you want to avoid plain text then Parquet is another option available out of the box:

```py
(sc.parallelize([(SparseVector(5, [0, 3], [1.0, -1.0]), )])
  .toDF()
  .write
  .parquet("/tmp/foo"))
```

```scala
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/tmp/foo")
df.printSchema()
// root
// |-- _1: vector (nullable = true)
```